# Tracking images in android programmatically

Tags: android

I want to track whenever an image enters the phone, it can be through camera, or through any third party app like whatsapp. I can't find anything that allw me to do so. 
Please help me, any help will be greately appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much android but you can keep a listener on the document directory where all images are stored and can count the number of images and store the count, next time when a new image is stored at that directory your listeners will call and count updated number of images. 
By this, you can keep track of added or removed images from that directory.

For listeners there are many ways, keep a observe like we have on iOS, or start a timer for each minute or second (through not the best way).